# JNLP with local codebase - how to update?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

It is legal to specify codebase like this:

```
<jnlp spec="6.0+"
    codebase="file:/c:/MyApp/"
    href="myapp.jnlp">
```

When you import this with JWS it creates desktop shortcut and the application is working.

However, one thing is very different from remote codebase. When I update those files while the application is running, it basically stops working flooded with `ClassNotFoundExceptions`. It seems as if JWS did not copy the jars, or copied them immediately as they are updated somehow overwriting those used by the running process.

How can I get it to work as if the files were remote? That is, copy files to cache and only check for updates on launch.

**EDIT**: I haven't found a way to do it and decided to go with a homebrew replacement. Along the way I found several bugs and made some observations that I summed up at http://squirrel.pl/blog/2011/11/24/java-web-start-bugs-offline-edition/. Posting it here in case it could be of any use for someone.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with the local codebase?

Comment: That's besides the point but: Reliance on slow and fragile web-based updates, and leveraging our existing system to pump all kinds of files, installations, updates etc. to select computers.

Comment: "fragile web-based updates".  Just ensure that if a file is updated it gets a new URL and update the JNLP file accordingly.

Comment: You should post your full jnlp file - the problem may be in there. However when I remember back in the days we also had lots of problems in the past using JWS and on/offline mode...

Answer (score 0):

For making your application auto updatable you should use `<update>` tag.

```
<update check="always" policy="always"/>
```

And also if you want, your application may run in offline use `<offline-allowed/>`.
Also for giving all security permissions you need to add tag of `<security>`.
                     Add the following tags to your JNLP file.

```
    <information>
        <offline-allowed/> 
    </information>

    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <update check="always" policy="always"/>

    <resources>
        <jar href="your-signed.jar" main="false" download="eager"/>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score -4):

In our application, the codebase is:

```
<jnlp codebase="http://xxxx.xxx.xxx/jars">
```

and, your jar file should put in your_webapp_root_directory/jars . For testing ,you can input a url in your browser:  http://xxxx.xxx.xxx/jars/xxxx.jar, if you can download the xxxx.jar file, it works.

Comment: Sorry, but I asked specifically about local codebase. I don't think you read the question at all.